# Telegram Bot & OpenAI - AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'Bot'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, openai-api

The code of the Telegram bot is as followings:

```
import openai
import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Set up the OpenAI API client
openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

# Set up the Telegram API client
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token="YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")

def handle_update(update):
  # Log the update
  logging.info("Received update: %s", update)
  
  # Get the message text and sender from the update
  text = update.message.text
  sender = update.message.from_user
  
  # Use the OpenAI API to generate a response
  response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=text,
    temperature=0.5,
    max_tokens=1024
  )
  
  # Log the response
  logging.info("Generated response: %s", response.text)
  
  # Send the response back to the sender
  bot.send_message(chat_id=sender.id, text=response.text)

# Set the update handler to our function
bot.set_update_handler(handle_update)

# Start the bot
bot.start_polling()
```

The error message I got is:

```
 File "/root/tgbot4.py", line 13, in <module>
    bot = telegram.bot(token="XXXXXXXXXXXX")
AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'bot'`
```

I used Telegram packages, one after one, to ensure I hit the right one. Just a stupid testing:

`python-telegram-bot`
`pyTelegramBotAPI-4.8.0`
`telegram 0.0.1`

Does anyone knows how I can solute it?

Comment: Hello. It should be `telegram.Bot(` with an uppercase b.

Comment: You are right. After uppercasing it, it looks like I'm encountering an AttributeError stating that the telegram module does not have an attribute called Bot.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is due to the incorrect usage of the telegram module. The correct attribute to create a Bot object is

> telegram.Bot

with an uppercase 'B'. Here's the corrected code:

```
import openai
import logging

#Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Set up the OpenAI API client
openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

# Set up the Telegram API client
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot(token="YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")

def handle_update(update):
  # Log the update
  logging.info("Received update: %s", update)
  
  # Get the message text and sender from the update
  text = update.message.text
  sender = update.message.from_user
  
  # Use the OpenAI API to generate a response
  response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=text,
    temperature=0.5,
    max_tokens=1024
  )
  
  # Log the response
  logging.info("Generated response: %s", response.text)
  
  # Send the response back to the sender
  bot.send_message(chat_id=sender.id, text=response.text)

# Set the update handler to our function
bot.set_update_handler(handle_update)

# Start the bot
bot.start_polling()
```